# Single Sign On Different Domains PHP

Tags: php, laravel, single-sign-on

From what I can see from different sources, all the SSO systems work with subdomains. I still have yet to find if SSO works with different domains.
For example appStore.com, appInternal.pt, appBlog.com, etc...

I'm going to assume it works with different domains(But please tell me if it doesn't). I've found a couple of packages, but the documentation is not very explicit and I got kind of confused.

Does anyone know of a good SSO package using PHP with good documentation? If it's with Laravel 5, even better!

Comment: Post your code, you tried so far.

Comment: I haven't written anything yet. I've only been reading a couple different documentation, but none to me were very explicit and so I had no idea what to do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If you need SSO on apps on different domains, then I recommend to use [SAML2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0).

There is a package for lavarel 5:
https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2

It uses [php-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml)

Comment: So the package for laravel 5 has everything i need? Because the documentation is not that much.
On the other hand, the php-saml has very extensive documentation but I don't know if it will work with Laravel..

Comment: On SAML there are 2 actors, Identty Providers and Service Providers.

With laravel-saml2 you will be able to add SAML support to the Lavarel apps, deploying a Service Provider that can be connected with any Identity Provider.

laravel-saml2 is a lavarel extension that uses php-saml, the main settings of the extension are php-saml settings.